# Oracle Responsys Link form in the main Campaign

Tags: forms, campaign-monitor, responsys

I have created a Form in Oracle responsys which is linked to my current table and form works completely fine. I have issue with generating the link for the form using built-in oracle responsys function `$prefilledform(crm_form_test)$`.

I just want to include `$prefilledform(crm_form_test)$` form link with my email campaign message so that it generate a link to my crm_form_test form. But its not generating form link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use
    `$formlink(crm_form_test, fields)$` in message body as  hyperlink so it will generate the link.